# ord() function in python returning a decimal

Tags: python, parsing, ssl, networking

I am trying to capture the TLS records in a pcap file where the data is normally in binary.
This is a part of a code that I found in Github :

```
def parse_tcp_packet(ip):
    """
    Parses TCP packet.
    """
    global streambuffer
    global encrypted_streams
    connection = '{0}:{1}-{2}:{3}'.format(socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src),
                                          ip.data.sport,
                                          socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst),
                                          ip.data.dport)
    if ord(ip.data.data[0]) in set((20, 21, 22)):
        stream = ip.data.data
    return
    parse_tls_records(ip, stream)
```

I have a question about the ord() function. If the data is written in binary, how can ord() work in this case and return 20,21 or 22? ord() function normally takes a character and returns its corresponding ASCII value, but in this case isn't it taking a binary as a parameter and returning its decimal correspondance?

Comment: Can you give some sample values for ip.data.data[0] ? As you said, yes ord() takes a character, but if your binary value (0 or 1) is passed as a string then it will give you output. Eg: ord('0') will give you 48

Comment: @Aparna the values that ip.data.data[0] should normally include are : 20 21 or 22.

Comment: @Aparna if it takes 0 or 1, then ord() will only give 48 or 49 as a result and never 20,21 or 22

Comment: If data is binary, then 0 and 1 can be the values ie. the reason why I have given the example of ord('0') and ord('1') and yes it cannot be 20/21/22. Also Its not the  ip.data.data[0] values that are 20 or 21 or 22, you are taking the ord() of those values. So please confirm the possible values for ip.data.data[0], whether its string or int or empty.